# Is it possible to access a users groups of friends on Facebook using Facebook graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

By which I mean when people can make sub lists of friends (i.e. work friends, family, close friends).

Is it possible to access these, as I would like my app to let the user target specific groups of friends to send messages to without having to manually choose each person?

Any searches for 'facebook groups', 'facebook friends groups' or 'friends list' turns up info on how to access the main friends list - which I can already do.

Has anyone managed to do this before? On the one hand I think it could be prohibited due to privacy issues, on the other hand I would think Facebook would prefer that users could message groups of friends in apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can most certainly get at this data.  There is a specific [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) called `user_friendlists`.  You'll have to request that permission from your users and once you have it, all you have to do is query this Graph end point -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/friendlists
```

It'll return data similar to this -

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "XXX", 
      "name": "Close Friends", 
      "list_type": "close_friends"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "YYY", 
      "name": "♥", 
      "list_type": "user_created"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "ZZZ", 
      "name": "Offline", 
      "list_type": "user_created"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "AAA", 
      "name": "The Office", 
      "list_type": "work"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "BBB", 
      "name": "Acquaintances", 
      "list_type": "acquaintances"
    }, 
    ...
```

As you can see, there are both types of friend lists here.  Automatically generated ones such as

- Close Friends
- Acquaintances

And some custom ones that I manually created -

- ♥
- Offline
- The Office

To get at the actual friends listed within these lists, you use the `/members` end point.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/FRIENDLIST_ID/members
```

---

This is only the *read* permission, you'll need the additional `manage_friendlists` to be able to create/edit those lists.

Comment: Thank you very much, I only need the read permission so this is great. Not sure why my earlier searches didn't turn this up..

Comment: I originally asked about this well in advance of starting the app, and today found out that "FRIENDLIST_ID/members" is not very reliable. Most of the time it returns an data array. Seems a few people have reported the same bug to Facebook, but there's no sign of it being fixed yet. In case anyone is confused, Lix was 100% correct that this is how you SHOULD be able to access the members of a group, the returned data is just not very reliable.

Comment: FRIENDLIST_ID/members should work fine. But the result will be empty if you don't have the right perms, like user_relationships when querying the "Family" list. Also the results will be a partial list when people on that list have privacy settings that filter them out from the results.

Comment: Getting friends list in the "members" way is not supported anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/friendlist/members

Comment: As of v2.0, this API only returns the friend lists themselves, not the list of people within each group. This API is thus primarily useful to allow you to render an audience selector when giving a person the opportunity to publish back to Facebook.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use the "next" pagination that it returns  ?

Comment: @Nateshbhat - It is usually an entire URL that you can use as-is to fetch the next page of results.