# How to fetch Facebook user's full friend list in Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-friends

I had a question concerning the Facebook iOS SDK that has been troubling me ever since i started my iOS project so I thought I could post it here to see if any of you had wisdom to share on this matter.

For my Facebook connected app to function properly I need to have access to the Facebook user's complete friend list along with their names, ids and profile pictures. After some intensive research I was surprised to learn that in version 2.0 of the Graph API Facebook has made it so that you can only retrieve a friend list of your friends who are currently using the app and have approved the app. This kind of data doesn't really work for my app as the main point is that you are met by your friend list as opposed to an empty list with only a few people who have approved the app.

My question is if there is any possible way for me to have access to the user's full friend list and display it in a table view with their profile picture without every single one of them having to approve the app. I don't mind if it is a complicated solution. The reason I ask this is because i have seen several apps that can fetch full friends lists such as:

http://www.connect.com

and

http://www.birthdayboardapp.com

and they must have found a way to do it as the way Connect displays the user's friend list is exactly the way I would like to do it i.e. in an iOS contacts app style way.

I would be grateful for any guidance or solutions,

Thanks Again!

P.S. Here are some questions I have previously looked at but do not suggest possible workarounds

[Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m)

[Get ALL User Friends Using Facebook Graph API - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850807/get-all-user-friends-using-facebook-graph-api-android)

Answer (score 5):

There are no workarounds, if it works in some other App then it just means that they are still using a Facebook App created before end of April 2014. They will stop getting the full friendlist after April 2015, when v1.0 Apps will get upgraded.

There are ways to get the whole friendlist like [invitable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.1) and [taggable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/taggable_friends), but those endpoints are supposed to get used for very specific tasks (for inviting in games and for tagging).

Comment: Thank you for your help, would the issue still remain if I submitted my app for some extra permissions to Facebook?

Comment: no, there are no extra permissions, this is a privacy feature to protect the privacy of those who don´t use the app.

Comment: So what would be the point of submitting your app to Facebook to gain access to extra permissions?