# How can we extract the complete Facebook friend list using Graph API in java script?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to extract friends list of a profile. I tried looking for the help and only thing I got is, `"/me/friends"`
but this call has a limitation. **This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.** 
I wanted to have the list of all the friends in my profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That´s how it works, you can´t get the full friendlist anymore. See the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

You can only get the friends who authorized your App too, for privacy reasons.

There are also plenty of other threads about that question already, for example:

- [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)
- [Get ALL User Friends Using Facebook Graph API - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850807/get-all-user-friends-using-facebook-graph-api-android)

Comment: thanks! Actually I am a stackoverflow guy and a cpp developer so bit unaware about these basic stuff