# Facebook4j paging to get all friends

Tags: java, facebook

I'm trying to get all friends of a user ID. But I don't understand how to do paging. This is my code:

```
ResponseList<Friend> results = facebook.getFriends(USER_ID);   
ArrayList<String> friendList = new ArrayList<String>();

// Getting Next page
Paging<Friend> paging1 = results.getPaging();
for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {  
    Friend f = results.get(i);
    String id = f.getId().toString();
    friendList.add(id);
    System.out.println(id);
}  

ResponseList<Friend> page2 = facebook.fetchNext(paging1);
for (int i = 0; i < page2.size(); i++) {    
    System.out.println(page2.size());
    Friend f = page2.get(i);
    String id = f.getId().toString();
    friendList.add(id);
    System.out.println(id);
}
```

With this code, I can only obtain the first 9 friends' IDs. It seems that the second paging doesn't retrieve anything. What's wrong?

Comment: It would be more useful to put `System.out.println(page2.size());` before your loop for iterating through the second page. At least that way, you will see how large page 2 is. Also, not sure why you are not using `for (Friend f : page2)`, which is more readable and less code.

Answer (score 2):

Does not look like paging is your problem if you only get 9 IDs. Most likely only 9 of your friends authorized the App. More information: [Get ALL User Friends Using Facebook Graph API - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850807/get-all-user-friends-using-facebook-graph-api-android)

Comment: if i try to obtain my friends with graph api explorer of facebook,  first paging show only 9 friends and the link for paging

Comment: what happens if you use the link for paging in the api explorer? do you get more friends?

Comment: exactly. there are only 9 friends who authorized your app, so there should actually not be paging.