# Get Facebook Friend List with Name

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using `Facebook SDK 4.x`, and i need to get friend list with name but i can't get it, 
i have also implemented this `graph API`

```
new GraphRequest(
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
"/me/friend",
null,
HttpMethod.GET,
new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
    }
}
).executeAsync();
```

and this is my `reponse`

```
response {Response: responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"summary":{"total_count":3},"data":[]}, error: null}
```

I am not getting friend list with name, if you have any idea than plz give me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Facebook only returns the list of those friends who have authorized your app. So its necessary that for each friend your app is installed.

Comment: Can i get friend name?

Comment: @MohitSuthar have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491479/fetch-friends-list-from-facebook-sdk-4-0-1-in-android-with-graph-api-2-2 answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solutions for using this

```
new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/taggable_friends",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.e("getFriendsDat",""+ response);
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

You will get friend list with name and detail.
you have to add `user_friends` permission and need to submit your app for review.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it´s `/me/friends`, not `/me/friend`. That being said, you can only get access to friends who authorized your App too, with the `user_friends` permission. The response means that you have 3 friends, but none of them authorized your App with `user_friends`.

More information: [Get ALL User Friends Using Facebook Graph API - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850807/get-all-user-friends-using-facebook-graph-api-android)

Comment: If any friend authorized my app than i get his name?

Comment: as you can read in my answer, a friend has to authorize your app with user_friends