# retrieve friend list members using facebook api v2.3

Tags: facebook-graph-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/members/

I'm using this api to retrieve user's friend list member. It always return empty data.

Is this like friends permission which only allow retrieve friends who already authorised my app?

It's in test app so permission review is not the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Of course, friends who did not authorize your App will not show up at all. More information about getting access to friends: [Get ALL User Friends Using Facebook Graph API - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850807/get-all-user-friends-using-facebook-graph-api-android)