# Facebook API integration in android .. to get my friendlist " me/friends " i want to get all data with name and user details

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

```
   My code is 
             if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                     facebook.authorize(this,
                    new String[]{"email","read_stream","read_custom_friendlists"},

                    new Facebook.DialogListener() {

                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            try {
                                getProfileInfo();



                            mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends ", new FriendsRequestListener());
                            /*  Bundle params = new Bundle();
                                params.putString("fields", "name, picture");
                                new FriendsRequestListener();*/


                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                System.out.println(e);
                                //Log.d("Error in fetching frnd list",String.valueOf(e));
                            }
                            //getProfileInfo();

                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook  acess_token


                        }
```

please checkout my code , I also tried graph API explorer but still on the same result don't know why .. !!
  it returns
        {
           "data": [   ], 
           "summary": {
           "total_count": 446
         } }

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the permission you are trying to use only gets you access to "friend lists", but NOT "friends". Make sure you understand the difference:

> read_custom_friendlists - Is the new name for read_friendlists Login permission. This is to clarify that the permission grants access to a person's custom friendlists, not the full list of that person's friends.

For `/me/friends` you would need the `user_friends` permission, but you will only get friends who authorized your App with `user_friends` too. More information about that can be found in countless Stackoverflow threads, for example: [Get ALL User Friends Using Facebook Graph API - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850807/get-all-user-friends-using-facebook-graph-api-android)