# How to get Facebook Friendlist to invite in Studio?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to login from `Facebook` successfully,but i am trying to get my friend list to invite them,for that i am following [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android)

but i am not able to get Facebook Friend list, can any one tell me that how to get Friend list of Facebook

Comment: to get friend list you must register your app as game on facebook are you doing this

Comment: @NavinGupta ok in facebook how to check that catagory of my app

Comment: @NavinGupta ok i did it as game..now is it possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.0 of the Graph API you can only get the friends who authorized your App, for privacy reasons: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends

for more information check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23926468/3134215)