# Android Facebook API, How to get friend list?Retuning Data is null, Even though API version is v2.5

Tags: android, facebook

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"summary":{"total_count":379},"data":[]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

Do I need to give extra permission, if so where? Also I am to get only user name and ID no other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.0 of the Graph API you can only get the friends who authorized your App, for privacy reasons:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends

for more information check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850807/get-all-user-friends-using-facebook-graph-api-android/23926468#23926468)

Comment: thanks, Also How can I get profile details, for below code I can get only user name and ID.Request request = Request.newMeRequest(
           Session.getActiveSession(),
           new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
           {

      @Override
      public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
        Response response) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Log.d(TAG,"user  "+user);
      }
           });
   
    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);

Comment: Ask for the fields you want. Or search StackOverflow because the question have been asked once a day at least for months