# I am not able to see all of my friend list using FQL

Tags: facebook

I am working on a web application where I have to use Facebook API to get my friend's data. I am facing 2 issues:

1. I am not able to see all of my friend list using FQL.
2. Does Facebook provide any API to find the list of places where my friend have visited like Restaurant or hotels?

Comment: post the code you tried

Comment: Aren't the results paginated?

Comment: I am using the Graph API Explorer and using following query : me/friends/?limit=5000  No result are not paginated. Even there is next page link , i am getting no result for next page. I have total 284 friend and only 7 are getting returned.

Comment: that´s not FQL, that´s the graph api. nevertheless, see my answer.

Comment: it means that 7 of your friends authorized the api explorer app, btw

Comment: Thank you everyone. Please post your comment why are you making it -1 and try to demotivate me

Answer (score 1):

1. FQL is deprecated, you really should not use it anymore. Also, you can only get a list of friends who authorized your App too. See this thread for more information: [Get ALL User Friends Using Facebook Graph API - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850807/get-all-user-friends-using-facebook-graph-api-android)
2. No, you can´t get the list of places your friends visited, for obvious privacy reasons.

Edit: As i can still see your deleted answer (which should have been a comment to my answer instead, i guess): To make this perfectly clear, you can NOT get all friends anymore. Again, check out the link i posted, all you need to know is in the accepted answer over there. And no, you can NOT get the list of places of your friends, just because they are available on Facebook for you. That does not mean an App can get them. About the dev group on Facebook: Try several times, and hopefully you are not trying with a fake account ;)

Comment: Thanks luschn! I wasn't aware that I need to post comment instead of answer. Here is thing which I have got so far.  1) I can't get all of my friend - got it.   2) Getting list of places visited by my friend : is there a way or not at all?   3) No, I wasn't using fake account.

Comment: 2) no, not at all. see my answer, it´s all in there already ;)