# Is it possible to get Facebook Friends List in Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

In my Application i want to Get the Friends list of Facebook. Is it possible to get the Friends list from Facebook SDK. I tried a lot but i am not get succeeded.
Can any one help me how to do this.

Comment: please look at the duplicate link, it explains every possibility to get friends

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course it is possible in android with [Graph Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph)

But for the security purpose the condition is that you only get the list of friend which is using your app. [Refer This Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends)  also check this [tutorial](https://www.numetriclabz.com/get-facebook-friends-list-in-android-list-view/) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23926468/3514144)

Following is some code snippet after login you will get

```
    GraphRequestAsyncTask graphRequestAsyncTask = new GraphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),"/me/friends",bundle, HttpMethod.GET,new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray rawName = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");

                        friendList = "{\"friendlist\":" + rawName.toString() + "}";
                        //String friendlist =  rawName.toString() ;
                        Log.d("TAG","response of friendlist is : " + friendList);

                       /* //coding for insert data in db.

                        String result = JSONUtils.insertUserprofile(imagePath, name, fbid, friendList);

                        Log.d("TAG", "Result of fb is : " + result);

                        if (result.toLowerCase().contains("success")) {

                            myPreferences.setFBUserId(Constant.PREFERENCE_LOGIN_FB, fbid);
                            //LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        }*/


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
```

Comment: "friendlist" is for the lists, not the friends

Comment: Yes exactly that was written bymistake and its a list who using your app :) you can edit answer dude.

Answer (score 0):

```
 login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                RequestData();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        }
    });
```

**Request Data**

```
 private void RequestData() {

    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

                new GraphRequest(
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                       // "/me/friends",
                        //"me/taggable_friends",
                        "me/invitable_friends",
                        null,
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                                try {
                                    JSONArray rawName = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                                    Log.e(TAG,"Json Array Length "+rawName.length());
                                    Log.e(TAG,"Json Array "+rawName.toString());


                                    for (int i = 0; i < rawName.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject c = rawName.getJSONObject(i);




                                        String name = c.getString("name");
                                        Log.e(TAG, "JSON NAME :"+name);

                                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("picture");
                                        Log.e(TAG,""+phone.getString("data"));

                                        JSONObject jsonObject = phone.getJSONObject("data");

                                        String url = jsonObject.getString("url").toString();
                                        Log.e(TAG,"@@@@"+jsonObject.getString("url").toString());


                                    }



                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                ).executeAsync();



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: @Surendran Have U Try This ?