# How to invite all friends of a Facebook user

Tags: android, ios, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

As I'm aware it is not possible (since Facebook API v2.0) to get a list of all Facebook friends of a Facebook user. It is just possible to get all friends of a user who already use the same app.

I searched the web and found the following links which confirm my hypotheses:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23926468/1325107
- Graph API Explorer
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite

So, in v1.0 it was possible, but the option to get a list of all friends of a user is not possible anymore since v2.0

**BUT:** How is it possible for an app like [Kiwi](https://itunes.apple.com/at/app/kiwi/id965609252?mt=8), to invite all Facebook friends in the background? If I install the app, and if I log in with Facebook, I can see clearly the "friend_list" permission, which gives Kiwi the ability to invite all Facebook friends without asking. Why is the "friend_list" permission possible for Kiwi? It can't be because they use v1.0, since this version is not available anymore as of April 2015. On [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) I'm not able to enhance my app with the "friend_list" permission, because it is not available in the list of permissions to choose from.

Thank you.

Comment: What possibilities you have for inviting friends is explained in the FAQ item you linked to already. So what else do you need?

Comment: I need an explanation, why Kiwi can invite all Facebook friends, but this is actually not possible for every other app. I saw a solution with `mutual_friends`, but they are missing an `facebook_id`, which is needed in order to invite someone programmatically (without the `facebook_dialog`)

Comment: AFAIK the only way to _invite_ is via the dialog.

Comment: Thank you. Kiwi is doing without the ordinary `facebook_dialog`, but with an customized one.